# vuejs reactive auth widget

Tags: vue.js, vuex, state-management

I have a login component in a navbar that switches between a login form and a logout button.

```
<div v-if="!loggedin">
      <form action="post" class="form-inline">
        <div class="container">
          <input v-model="username" class="form-control mr-2" placeholder="Usuario" type="text" />
          <input v-model="password" class="form-control mr-2" placeholder="Password" type="text" />
          <button @click.prevent="login" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <button @click.prevent="logout" class="btn btn-danger">Logout</button>
    </div>


export default {
  data() {
    return {
      username: "",
      password: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    login() {
      if (this.username !== "" && this.password !== "") {
        this.$store.dispatch("obtainToken", {
          username: this.username,
          password: this.password
        });
      }
      console.log(this.logedin); // prints false on success
    },
    logout() {
      this.$store.dispatch("deleteToken");
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["loggedin"])
  }
};
```

The authentiation is backed by `vuex` and jwt

```
   export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    jwt: localStorage.getItem('jwt'),
  },
  getters: {
    loggedin: state => {
      return state.jwt != null
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    updateToken(state, newToken) {
      localStorage.setItem('jwt', newToken)
      state.jwt = newToken
    },
    removeToken(state) {
      localStorage.removeItem('jwt')
      state.jwt = null
    }
  },
  actions: {
    obtainToken(context, credentials) {
      console.log(credentials)
      Axios.post('auth/token/', credentials)
        .then((resp) => {
          context.commit('updateToken', resp.data.token);
          console.log(context.state.jwt)
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))
    },
    deleteToken(context) {
      context.commit('removeToken')
    }
  },
  modules: {}
});
```

Let's say I have the token stored if I press the logout button the widget immediatly goes back to show the login form. But not the other way around. Afther authenticating I have to refresh the page to make vue show the authenticated state part of my widget. This is affecting other parts of the app as the do not show up.

Don't know why it works with after logging out and not in. Both rely on reading the store getter. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind changed `resp.data.token` to `resp.data` and fixed it.